# How to resolve Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON

Tags: database

I have Set Up a Remote Database to Optimize wordpress Site Performance with MySQL on Ubuntu 16.04. I downloaded the wordpress onto my web server. When I Navigate to the public IP address associated with my web server, i get "Error establishing a database connection".

With wordpressdebug mode set to true, the details of the error is:

```
 Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/3159): Connections using insecure 
 transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON. in /var/www
 /html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1538
```

I have tested remote connection using the remote user and I am able to connect. This means my database server is running and my remote user credentials are also correct.

What may be causing this and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The quickest fix would be to go to
`sudo vim /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` and remove the:

`"requiresecuretransport = on"`

Then restart via:

`sudo systemctl restart mysql`

Answer (score 0):

adding this function below to my wp-config.php solved the problem:
define('DB_SSL', true);

**Reference**:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142632/wordpress-ssl-mysql-is-this-configuration-possible